# Type guarding not narrowing generic type as expected. 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'number'

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function that interpolates values, meant to be used for animating objects. Values can be numbers, arrays of numbers, or objects containing numbers/arrays of numbers, though this isn't important for the problem about to be described.

Here is a skeleton for the source, which can be found at this [TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAGwKYCcAOBxVYMwQA8AKgHwAUw6cAtgFyIkA0iUcjLimNA5uqgDOgxmBC0ARhgCUnRAG8AUIhWIYwRBSgBPTKjgbqdRAEIAvGba79G9tIXLVTqAAsaAd0QBRdDXQUAAxIXVCs9QUQDRAByI1poxABDMAATGPYElLhEMDgoRFpEqAgXADpEbDzEABJ5HT0ouIBfJNSauuso9iaA6QBuRxUmxUHEQXcYYpdNeptEOPslJycIRMFQ6LFJDGj6UeXVdRnO22yLS03xKXRo6X2D5YEoEHQkNCwAOSuMKhpaVnYrB4cH4QkE-UQAHpId5fHB0OVoiQEhA4CBkGkpGowIIoMlYEVUGkJq5Wkl0BJJuhEuhtGFQu4XIRpqj0ZjQuABMhCWl2DEttdoqV7gdUMh1iKHipXB5YX5Al4AB56aBE%20mRDTRDJsbJYgUYUq9PpQmEfKqCF6hFxwTzuBlojGIVAANwwiF4qHyIQEwqlq3WMTgEgAVqhoLtJU5oYgAJIaGnU7SsCDIBChZJpSYYQmRV3oJ2JEpqKCoWi%20qWqaNxyIhsNQZOp-CtNICCAvANwPPcGh6dCwITlg4pVDARLoqB7CuVmG5fLvTAAWkSEjQALcNqdcIRo2Gil3oEgsAQKAwmC%20238uJpE5y33QrDwKVEd6BfAEwmfF9kt4vDicTxeJArz7RAAGpNEfRAFzGPE%203sAAqbsQXfQQBiaIA):

```
function lerpGeneric<T>(from: T, to: T, progress: number): T {
    if (typeof from !== typeof to) {
        throw Error(`The types of 'from' and 'to' do not match. Got ${typeof from} and ${typeof to}`);
    }

    switch (typeof from) {
        case 'number':
            if (typeof to === 'number')
                return lerpNumber(from, to, progress); // Error! 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'number'.
            else
                throw Error(`Expected type of 'to' to be number but got ${typeof to}.`);
        case 'object':
            // If array, clone and iterate over each item.
            // If object, clone and recurse over properties.
        default:
            // not lerp-able, throw error.
    }

}

// Linearly interpolates a value. Progress is a number from 0 to 1.
function lerpNumber(start: number, end: number, progress: number): number {
    return start + (end - start) * progress;
}
```

At the line marked with  `// Error!`. the compiler complains about the type of what is being returned. To me, the type checks of the `switch` and `if` should (effectively) narrow the type of `T` to `number`, but this doesn't happen. The compiler says `'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'number'.` Interestingly, VSCode suggests the type of `from` and `to` to be be `T & number`, rather than just `number`, like I would expect. Anyway, what is the compiler warning about? I can't think of any type `T` where `typeof T === 'number'` yet returning a `number` could potentially result in a runtime error. Is there a way to correct handle types here, or do I need to just perform a type assertion here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript incorrectly infers that the type of `from` is `T & number` when, in fact, it can only be `number` at that point. It looks like a TypeScript bug and you're certainly [not the first](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2214) person to notice it.

Until this TypeScript bug is fixed, use `if` instead of `switch`.